# How to remove all jQuery validation engine classes from element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-validation-engine

I have a plugin that is cloning an input that may or may not have the jQuery validation engine bound to it.

so, it's classes may contain e.g. `validate[required,custom[number],min[0.00],max[99999.99]]` or any combination of the jQuery validation engine validators.

The only for sure thing is that the class begins with `validate[` and ends with `]`, but to make it more complicated as in the example above, there can be nested sets of `[]`.

So, my question is, how can I remove these classes (without knowing the full class) using jQuery?

Comment: a regex might be your best bet, jQuery can remove and add classes if you already know the name but unless you want to have a removeClass() call for every possible combination you would be better off doing a regex and using pure JS to find and remove the classes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating hidden input and appending error to other element with jquery validation engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132955/validating-hidden-input-and-appending-error-to-other-element-with-jquery-validat)

Comment: @Sparky This question is not a duplicate of that one, yes they are both about the validation engine, but this question is more generic and aimed at how can we remove classes from an element when we don't know the full class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation, It's not using regex, but meh, who said it had too?

```
//'first validate[ required, custom[number], min[0.00], max[99999.99] ] other another';
var testString = $('#test')[0].className; 

function removeValidateClasses(classNames) {
    var startPosition = classNames.indexOf("validate["),
        openCount     = 0, 
        closeCount    = 0,
        endPosition   = 0;

    if (startPosition === -1) {
        return;
    }

    var stringStart     = classNames.substring(0, startPosition),
        remainingString = classNames.substring(startPosition),
        remainingSplit  = remainingString.split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < remainingString.length; i++) {
        endPosition++;
        if (remainingString[i] === '[') {
            openCount++;
        } else if (remainingString[i] === ']') {
            closeCount++;
            if (openCount === closeCount) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //concat the strings, without the validation part
    //replace any multi-spaces with a single space
    //trim any start and end spaces
    return (stringStart + remainingString.substring(endPosition)) 
           .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
           .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
$('#test')[0].className = removeValidateClasses(testString);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might actually be simpler to do that without JQuery. Using the className attribute, you can then get the list of classes using split(), and check whether the class contains "validate[".

```
var classes = $('#test')[0].className.split(' ');
var newClasses = "";

for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
    if(classes[i].indexOf('validate[') === -1){
        newClasses += classes[i];
    }
}

$('#test')[0].className = newClasses
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar, as `validate[ required, custom[number], min[0.00], max[99999.99] ]` and similar variations are valid!

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is even more simple. You just have to replace `field_id` with the `id` of that element and if the element has classes like `some_class different_class validate[...]` it will only remove the class with validate, leaving the others behind.

```
var that ='#"+field_id+"';
  var classes = $(that).attr('class').split(' ');
  $.each(classes, function(index, thisClass){
 if (thisClass.indexOf('validate') !== -1) {
$(that).removeClass(classes[index])
}
 });
```